# Windows Batch Copy file by filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

The file I want to copy is located in "C:\Report\" and the filename I want to copy is something like "rptXXXX.txt".
What I want to do is write a batch that copy the file that the filename is start with "rpt".

The destination folder is "F:\Project\Report\".

Comment: What happens if the file is "name DATE other.txt" and you want to use DATE as the specific value to copy the file?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This should work, you can use an * as a wildcard:

```
xcopy e:\foo\rpt*.txt e:\foo2
```

or in your case,

```
xcopy C:\Report\rpt*.txt F:\Project\Report\
```

Comment: yeah sure , btw how if the file already exist at the destination folder , i would like to overwrite it.

Comment: /Y will overwrite all without prompt. /D will overwrite only those that are newer. you can also use `xcopy /?` for more options